# How to make a new .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I want to make new file but first choose directory.
This code works but a directory is already set

```
new_file = input("File name\n")
new_file = new_file.lower().replace(".", "").replace(" ", "_")
print(new_file)
open_file = open('D:\Python projects\%s.py' % new_file, 'w')
```

Also tried like this but not happen

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
new_file = input("Name file\n")
open_file = open(f"{file_path}\%s.py" % new_file, 'w')
```

Comment: maybe `askdirectory` instead of `askopenfilename` ?

Answer (score 0):

askdirectory should work. file_path = filedialog.askdirectory

Comment: Thanks.
I have 1 more question. How to get directory without name file?

fileName = file_path.name.split('/').pop()

this show only name I want show only directory withut name file

Comment: use os.path.split ex: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-split-method/